# git send-email subject doesn't change despite --subject option

Tags: git

I'm trying to set the subject of a patch I'm sending manually, but for some reason it always picks the subject of the patch commit instead of the one I supply to it.

I'm running it as

```
git send-email --compose --subject="blah" file.patch
```

and even though I can see the subject "blah" in the editor window that opens, after I save it and attempt to email the patch the subject that is mailed is still the same as the patch commit message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong: `--compose` tells `git send-email` that you want to write a "cover letter" with the subject you gave with `--subject`. The actual commit will then be sent as a reply to this "cover letter", *with the first line of the commit message as a subject*.

This is the "standard format" that is understood by `git am` so that the recipient can apply the patch and get the same result. This means that **changing the subject of the patch email will change the commit message**: your recipient would get a *different* commit, which is probably not what you want.

If you really want to send a commit by email with a custom subject, you can prepare your patch with `git format-patch` and then attach it to an email written with your usual MUA. This way the recipient can `git am` the attachment.

Comment: TIL: 'MUA' means mail user agent (or makeup artist).